# Include all javascript files in an asp.net mvc project with ONE include

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the asp.net mvc 4.0 intranet project I see this in the _layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script>
```

What means /Scripts/js ?

My question is about the "js"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the optimization framework which minifies and bundles your JavaScript for you. This include assumes the default registration. For more introduction, see [Scott Guthrie's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx).